# How many days have a dataset has records per each month in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with more than 150.000 records of tv programming data, dozens of channels, but not all channels have data for all days.

I want to group them by channel, year and month, count how many days on each month there are records for each channel.

Here a small piece of the data frame

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"channel": {"631": "CBR", "632": "CBR", "633": "CBR"}, "year": {"631": "2014", "632": "2014", "633": "2014"},
     "month": {"631": "01", "632": "01", "633": "01"}, "day": {"631": "06", "632": "06", "633": "06"},
     "t1": {"631": 1388967300000, "632": 1388973300000, "633": 1388974500000},
     "title": {"631": "title 1", "632": "title 2", "633": "title 3"}})
```

I've tried groupby this way

```
grouped = df.groupby(['channel', 'year','month', 'day']).count().reset_index()
```

So I get this result for one channel at month 12.

[image]

But what I want is to count how many disctinct days exist for each channel on each month.

For the example above I woild have

WBT | 2014 | 12  |  31

I'm using python 3.5.2 and Pandas 0.19.1.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Is that what you want: `df.groupby(['channel', 'year','month'])['day'].nunique().reset_index()`?

Comment: Thanks @MaxU, it does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
In [110]: df.groupby(['channel','year','month'])['day'].apply(lambda x: len(x.unique()))
Out[110]: 
channel  year  month
CBR      2014  01       1
Name: day, dtype: int64
```

or, as suggested by @MaxU and @TedPetrou you could use .nunique(), like this:

```
In [5]: df.groupby(['channel','year','month'])['day'].nunique()
Out[5]: 
channel  year  month
CBR      2014  01       1
Name: day, dtype: int64
```

`nunique()` seems to be the clever option in terms of performance, see below:

```
In [6]: %timeit df.groupby(['channel','year','month'])['day'].apply(lambda x: len(x.unique()))
The slowest run took 4.39 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100 loops, best of 3: 4.42 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit df.groupby(['channel','year','month'])['day'].nunique()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.05 ms per loop
```

Comment: Theres a direct dispatching method `nunique` that removes the need for apply. See @MaxU's comment

Answer (score 0):

```
# not add 'day' in groupby 
bydays = df.groupby(['channel','year','month'])

print(bydays['day'].count())
```

Comment: Thanks @Danil.V, I tried it, but doing this way what I get is the total number od records per day in a month, not how many days in a month have records.